# Onmouseover in css effect pushes image down, can't figure out display: inline-block code

Tags: css, image, resize, hover, onmouseover

I have a problem when re-sizing my images with `CSS` on with a `mouseover` effect. I know there are some questions on the site that had the same problem and it had to do with the `float: left` code that I am also using, however my code is a bit different since I have other effects and can't seem to get the `display: inline-block` code to work properly for my situation.

I think it might as simple as one line of code but I don't see it.

1. I have a sort of window of 4 images that open up `onmouseover`,
   however when the images furthest to the right opens up it drops
   down. How do I prevent the browser from doing this?
2. The second question is how do I make the other 3 images norrower
   when hover on the 4th image?

Appreciate any help. Here is the code:

http://mycodeonline.blogspot.nl/

Comment: Could you put the sample into a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use CSS overflow to achieve what you are talking about.  Here is an example set up with your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/7HnzF/

I added an extra div around it all and a couple classes.  One is the div for the images to move in so they won't hit the edge and drop down.  The `<div class="window"></div>` you can set a px width to of what you need.  The overflow of that div will just be hidden.